# Can't run custom bash script in Applescript

Tags: xcode, bash, applescript, sh

Here is my code:

```
set scriptpath to (path to current application as text)
set scripty to do shell script scriptpath & "Contents:Resources:moveskript " & variable1 & variable2 with administrator privileges
```

And it says this:

```
2015-12-08 16:40:33.565 Move[9093:63037] *** -[AppDelegate mybuttonhandler:]: /bin/sh: HD2:Users:gff:Library:Developer:Xcode:DerivedData:Move-fxtmdhtebdbqpbemfeknbexosigm:Build:Products:Debug:Move.app:Contents:Resources:moveskript: command not found (error 127)
```

Even though the command is there, and it works when I run it through terminal.

Comment: You stuck all the text together into a single word and tried to run it it looks like. The shell can't find a command by the name "HD2:Users:gff:Library:Developer:Xcode:DerivedData:Move-fxtmdhtebdbqpbemfeknbexosigm:Build:Products:Debug:Move.app:Contents:Resources:moveskript" anywhere. You need spaces between the command and arguments and you might need a shell path not whatever that colon-separated path is to have the shell understand the path to the command.

Comment: In your very similar question a few days ago I suggested to use `NSBundle` to get the path to the resource since you're writing an AppleScriptObjC app anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The *"Contents:Resources:moveskript"* syntax is for Finder path object, not a POSIX path.

**Mistakes:**

1. Combine full path: `set moveScriptPath to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:moveskript"`
2. Get POSIX path: `set posixPath to POSIX path of moveScriptPath`

Currently the path is causing the error 127. After fixing that, if you *"moveskript"* doesn't have any errors it should be fine. Look out for paths with spaces, special characters etc., use `quoted form of somePathWithWhitespace` in apple script. [More info](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html).

This *'moveskript'*, guessing from the name, it moves two to place where user might not have read/write privileges, FYI there is a shell command `mv` just for that. Open Terminal and type `man mv` to read more about it. Also is it an apple scrip too? Why not just use a handler inside the same script? If so you have to do:

```
do shell script ("/usr/bin/osascript " & quoted form of posixPath & " " & quoted form of file1 & " " & quoted form of file 2) with administrator privileges
```

I'm guessing you're calling this from an application and not applet, so there is not need to use applescript to move stuff, again look into `mv`. Even better use the Cocoa framework because it can do all the work, [more info](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Swift_on_iOS_8).